# Generation of unlabeled acyclic digraphs

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-algorithms, directed-acyclic-graph

I'm looking for an algorithm to efficiently generate all unlabeled acyclic digraphs of a given order.  (By "unlabeled" I mean that no two of the generated digraphs should be isomorphic.)
Thanks

Edit: removed the word "enumeration" from title; I made the original title "Enumeration/generation of unlabeled acyclic digraphs" in a misguided effort to increase the number of possible answers; I had conjectured, incorrectly, that enumeration algorithms could be easily adapted to generate all the enumerated digraphs; now I realize this conjecture is wrong, hence the edited title emphasizes that I'm interested in an algorithm for generating (and not just enumerating) unlabeled acyclic digraphs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are looking for an implementation, Sage knows how to generate general digraphs up to isomorphism

```
sage: len(list(digraphs(4)))
218
```

You can then plug in a "test" method if you just want the acyclic ones :

```
sage: len(list(digraphs(4, property = lambda g:g.is_directed_acyclic())))
31
```

It returns 302 digraphs on 5 vertices, and 5984 on 6 vertices. But I am a bit scared to try larger values :-)

By the way, giving those values to the OEIS returns the expected sequence :

http://oeis.org/search?q=1,2,6,31,302,5984&language=english&go=Search

Which also happens to contain several references that may suit your taste :-)

Nathann

Answer (score 3):

[Counting unlabeled acyclic digraphs -- R. W. Robinson](http://www.springerlink.com/content/1716582847315l87/)